# pure html pages without functionality in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am creating a web application with asp.net core that has a lot of pure HTML pages without any functionality.
How do I add these pages to the application?  Should I create an action method for each page?

Comment: either as HTML pages, or as views. Up to you and how you want to use them or access them. There's no right answer

Comment: pure html pages are fine, but why you are looking for action methods? as per @Amy, go with separate folder in your solution for static html files.

Comment: i want to access to HTML pages.

Comment: @NnN thank you.This is my answer

Comment: I don't believe this should be marked as duplicate as it is tagged with `asp.net-core`.  The duplicate answer is for ASP.NET MVC from 4 years ago and may not apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a folder within Views folder where you are going to place your html pages, **PlainHTML** for example.  Then when you run your application you can go to ~/PlainHTML/View.html

Comment: I cant reach pages in any folder except files in wwwroot folder

Comment: @eyvaz Put your HTML files in `wwwroot` and make sure you're using `app.UseStaticFiles()` in your `Startup.cs`.